# Is it possible to specify that an options is required with boost::program_options?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I can use all other public members of the class typed_value define in value_semantic.hpp such as: default_value, implicit_value, zero_tokens, multitoken, notifier, etc.

But even if the member "required()" is also there, I cannot use it.

I got the error:

```
‘class boost::program_options::typed_value<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, char>’ has no member named ‘required’
```

---

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your boost version maybe too old? I found required() in the docs for 1.45, but not in the ones for 1.34 - I don't know when it changed.

Comment: You are right. I had installed 1.45 but I was linking on the old one. My bad